# POWERSHELL - Define a default parameter set name ONLY if a parameter is specified

Tags: powershell

I have this code here (I simplified) :

```
Enum Region {
    AU
    BE
    BR
    CA
}

Function Get-AccByCountry
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='With_Specific_Countries')]
    PARAM (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
        ParameterSetName='With_Specific_Countries')]
        [Region[]]
        $Regions,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
        ParameterSetName='Without_Specific_Countries')]
        [Region[]]
        $NotRegions
    )

    #BEGIN{}

    PROCESS
    {
        Write-Verbose -Message "Starting global process"

        IF($Regions){
            foreach($r in $Regions){
                [String]$r = $r
                Get-AccByCountryLocalized $r -Verbose
            }
        }ELSEIF($NotRegions){
            foreach($PR in [Enum]::GetValues([type]"Region")){
                [String]$PR = $PR
                IF($NotRegions -notcontains $PR)
                {
                    $PR
                    Get-AccByCountryLocalized $PR -Verbose
                }
            }
        }ELSE{
            Get-AccByCountryGlobal -Verbose
        }
    }

    #END{}

}
```

So I can call Get-AccByCountry either with no parameters specified, regions specified, of the regions I don't want specified (3 possibilities).

These 3 calls work :

```
Get-AccByCountry
Get-AccByCountry -Region AU,BE
Get-AccByCountry -NotRegions AU,BE
```

But when I try :

```
Get-AccByCountry AU,BE
```

It doesn't work ! It gives me this error (in French) :

```
Get-AccByCountry : Impossible de trouver un paramètre positionnel acceptant l'argument « System.Object[] ».
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Get-AccByCountry CA,AU
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (:) [Get-AccByCountry], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Get-AccByCountry
```

I specified the DefaultParameterSetName, but it's not taken into account.

I want that my function to take the set 'With_Specific_Countries' everytime I give a parameter without specifying a set.

How should I do ?

Comment: Just add `Position = 0` to the first parameter : `[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName='With_Specific_Countries', Position = 0)]`

Comment: Was it that easy ! But why was it necessary in the case where I specified a default parameter set name ? Because that's why I didn't put the Position = 0 at first

Comment: Without `Position` you are just allowing for Named parameters. The `DefaultParsmeterSetName` is used when no parameters are given